# Add binary to ubuntu applications when no install or configure folder in tar.gz

Tags: apt, software-installation, tar

I am on Ubuntu 17.10 I have downloaded a program for Linux, unzipped it and found it has no README, INSTALL or config folder. Hence, to make it runnable from the prompt I followed this: [Install tar.gz , but no configure folder on install file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/639389/install-tar-gz-but-no-configure-folder-on-install-file?rq=1)

What I would like also to do, however, is to associate some extensions to the binary that I installed. As you would do by right-clicking on an extension, select "Open With Other Application" and selecting the app to run it. Unfortunately, the app I have installed is not listed in Ubuntt's list of applications.

Is there any way in which I can make the binary run every time I double-click on a file with a particular extension?

Bonus: may I have the app popping up in the GNOME app menu? (as if it was installed from the Software center or apt-get)

The program is Gephi (v 0.9.2)

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow the installation process from the Gephi website ?

**https://gephi.org/users/install/**

If you have java installed, you just have to use the command

```
./bin/gephi
```

from the folder where you untar the file

you can also just double click on this same file from the file manager

Comment: Yes and everything works with regards to that, having added it to path I can also run it typing gephi from everywhere. I was wondering more in general how I could add it as an application in the gnome window and how to associate its extensions to it. For instance, say I have a file abc.gexf, I want to double click on the file and have gephi starting and loading it. Do you think if that is possible?

Comment: Take a look at this thread : https://askubuntu.com/questions/289337/how-can-i-change-file-association-globally I think this is what you're looking for